# Java application can connect to a specific ip and port but port isn't open in the firewall

Tags: java, tcp, firewall, serversocket

The following java code listens for incoming connections on a specific port. I see that clients can connect but how is that possible if the server port is not open in the firewall?

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 5555);
serverSocket.bind(addr);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Firewalls normally don't filter local traffic. Try from a different machine

Comment: Also, you should bind on a LAN address if you want your service available on the LAN: if you bind to localhost, it will only be reachable locally. (sorry didn't notice this before)

Answer (score 1):

> I see that clients can connect

Only if those clients are in the same localhost, because your server port is bound to 127.0.0.1:5555, not 0.0.0.0:5555.

> but how is that possible if the server port is not open in the firewall?

Because the firewall doesn't have anything to do with communications within the localhost.

Comment: I've changed "localhost" by the server ip and clients on the LAN can connect with it. I don't understand why.

Comment: Because there is no firewall between them and you?

Comment: No. I'm using two computers with Windows 7 with the firewall running. The client application send a message using a socket to the other computer (ip 10.0.2.6 and port 5000). The server is listening in this port and receives the message.